# Force remove cached

Tags: git

May I know what is the command in terminal to force remove cache from GIT?

As per what I know to remove GIT is 
    git rm --cached thefilename

But now I am getting an error

error: 'tutorial.h' has staged content different from both the file and the HEAD
(use -f to force removal)

So, may I know how am I going to remove this?

Comment: yeap so I wanted to know the complete command....

Answer (score 20):

```
git rm --cached -f thefilename
```